# What uniform is in this picture? and when the unit would have been active?

Tags: world-war-two, military, caribbean

I believe it belongs to the Caribbean Regiment (British Islands), but I heard most of the records no longer exist. I also think they fought during WWII, but I’m not sure the person in uniform would have been of age to fight 1939-45.[image: b&w pic of man in uniform]

Comment: I'm a bit worried this one may be unusually difficult, due to how out of focus all of the typical identifying marks of the uniform are. Normally, this is where I'd advise trying to take and upload a better picture, but I think in this case the flaws may be in the photo itself.

Comment: I’m afraid it’s the original photo that is of poor quality. I tried taking a new pic, but it is no better.